# Java/Scala library for algebra, mathematics

Tags: java, math, scala, linear-algebra, algebra

Can you advise me some flexible and powerful, yet fast library which could cover SciPy (both in performance and functionality).  I found SciPy very expressive - but I want to try something in Scala.

I read a little about Scala - but is not as featured as SciPy. Any alternatives? Maybe Java library?

Comment: Did you try apache library ( http://commons.apache.org/math/ )?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482305/java-scientific-packages-similar-to-scipy

Comment: @Superfilin Yeah, but it includes Scala, which opens up the field a bit.

Comment: Its not duplicate - i was looking for package with something like matlab style - so more for scala.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The functionality in Scipy is rather Matlab-like.  So the question is whether you just want the core linear algebra / vector-matrix mathematics operations, or all sorts of things like clustering.

If you are not aware of both [Scalala](https://github.com/scalala/Scalala) (now called [Breeze](http://www.scalanlp.org/breeze-0-1/)) and [ScalaLab](http://code.google.com/p/scalalab/), you should check them out--maybe they'll suit your needs.

If you need a more diverse library, there are a couple of Java libraries that might be suitable: [CERN Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) and [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/); these are intended to be used in Java style, however, and you're pretty much limited to using them that way from within Scala.  (Though of course you can wrap the bits that you use particularly heavily in something prettier.)

Comment: ScalaLab + apache commons math sound like a good combination.
But for now I didn't find anything as good as (in terms of composition and strength) as SciPy

Comment: Scalala seems to be deprecated and merged  into [breeze](https://github.com/dlwh/breeze) now

Answer (score 4):

There are **[scalala](https://github.com/scalala/Scalala)** (scala linear algebra library) and **[ScalaLab](http://code.google.com/p/scalalab/)** (more like a Matlab scala-environment)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [la4j](http://la4j.org) (Linear Algebra for Java) library that can be used from Scala environment but it doesn't contain any Scala features like hi-order functions since Java doesn't support it. la4j was designed to be used in imperative environment (not functional). So if you want to use it in functional way - [Scalala](https://github.com/scalala/Scalala) is the best chose.